# Is there a way to find where the error is coming from when printing elements from a LinkeList?

Tags: java

```
    public void Room(){
        int i = 0;
        int split = numTunnels(tunnels)*tunnelLength(tunnel_length);
        LinkedList<Double> room = new LinkedList<>(Creation());
        Iterator it = rooms.iterator();
        while(i <= split){
        System.out.print(it.next()+ " ");
        i++;
        if(i == split){
            System.out.println();
            i = 0;
        }
        }
}
```

When i run it, i get the output i want plus this error that i don't know what to do about, where is it coming from.

```
1.0 1.1 1.2 1.3 
2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 
3.0 3.1 3.2 3.3 
4.0 4.1 4.2 4.3 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException 
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:894) 
    at robot.wars.Colony.Room(Colony.java:45) 
    at robot.wars.RobotWars.main(RobotWars.java:18) 
C:\Users\dioni\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The  following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\Users\dioni\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java  returned: 1 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: You want to iterate over more elements than there are available. You need to also check `it.hasNext()`

Comment: @WJS i had already tried that with few other things but the error persists.

Comment: @Lino that seemed to work, pretty quick fix thankfully.

Comment: Please provide more of a description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Change your while statement to `while(it.hasNext()){`.

or iterate this way using the implicit iterator of the enhanced for loop.

```
for (double d : rooms) {
     System.out.print(d + " ");
}
```